# Cannot pass java.lang.long to com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.invoke

Tags: java, com, long-integer, jacob

I'm trying to pass java.lang.long variable to com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.invoke but I get below exception:

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: A COM exception has been encountered:
At Invoke of: SomeMethod
Description: 8002000a / Out of present range.
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Dispatch.java:625)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.callN(Dispatch.java:453)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.invoke(ActiveXComponent.java:476)
```

SomeMethod in COM Object is accepting long type. Could anybody help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COM `long` type is 32 bits. Use the JAVA `int` type.